# how to get tooltip like effects on touching on a component in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way or class to show tooltip like effects on touching on component to provide extra information instead of displaying it on dialog box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LayeredPane`, `LayeredLayout` (on which `LayeredPane` is based) or `GlassPane` each of which has its advantages/drawbacks.

Generally `InteractionDialog` is a dialog type that doesn't "block" and can float and its based on the `LayeredPane`.

See:
http://www.codenameone.com/blog/not-a-dialog-again

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/completion-ios-7-update-and-the-20m-mark.html

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/walk-thru-tutorial